# Error Loading Operating System when booting to a dual partitioned USB drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, partitioning, hp-elitebook

I seem to have an odd issue with a dual partitioned usb drive, here is my setup:

I created 2 partitions on my external hard drive.  One partition has my bootable Windows environment ( WinPE 3.0 ) NTFS @ 10.0GB - which I set active -  and the another partition is NTFS @ ~900GB.

I can boot to this external at anytime via any desktop (HP 7800-8200 SFF) .  However, when I take my external to any laptop(HP 2530p, HP 8540p, etc)  - I cannot boot to my external harddrive.  I this error when I manually specify the system to boot to my USB external Hdd: "Error loading operating system".

This is everything that I have tried[which failed]:

- Shrinking the partition that holds my bootable OS to 1GB
- Performing a FULL format of that partition as

  - FAT
  - FAT32
  - NTFS
- Changed the BIOS of the laptop between both AHCI and IDE
- Factory defaulted BIOS of the laptop
- Doing a Chkdsk on the external hdd & repair any bad sectors
- Made sure my bootable partition was marked as ACTIVE and PRIMARY (not logical)
- Changed the USB port used
- Put the WinPE into both partitions

Also, I tried booting to a bootable USB drive (same files, NTFS) with only one partition, which worked.

Note: I checked the MBR of the bootable drive & it looks correct.  I dont think this is my issue because it CAN boot to the USB drive when connected to any desktop

The BIOS information on my laptop (HP 2530p) is as follows: ROM Revision 68PSU Ver. F.21 08/02/2012.

Why does this work on my desktops, but not my laptops?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but if your active WinPE partition is after other partitions, could that cause the computer to ignore the 'active' flag on some computers?

Comment: well I also tried putting the same winpe on both partitions and I still received this error :(  - I will update the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this.... It seems I wasn't the only one with this issue.

The HP 2530p Elitebooks had a BIOS issue that gets resolved after flashing the BIOS to Revision [F22.  Download is located here](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=3782222&prodNameId=3782253&swEnvOID=2101&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ob-114594-1).